# Is it possible to synchronize multiple databases in to 1 database with the same tables?

Tags: replication, data-synchronization

We are facing a situation where we have 5 different businesses with comparable data and are building 1 single application to deliver their data to common customers.

In order to do this, the plan is to synchronize all data in to 1 central database.

the way that is currently planned, is to work via webservices and each business will manage their own data via those webservices. This however will give each business extra work load in order to keep their data integrity in check via those web services.

I was wondering if there is a better way. Is it possible for those 5 businesses to create some sort of "shadow" tables of the new central database and fill that up... So that a Third party software can handle all the issues of synchronization (or replication if this is the correct term)?

Is such a thing possible and does this type of software exist for sql server and/or oracle?

Thank you,

Comment: If you are looking for SQL Server - many to one T-Rep, I have [answered it here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/43995/8783). It will give you an idea on how you should configure and implement it.