# Merge Replication From Multiple Express to Central

Tags: sql-server, merge-replication

So I am trying to setup a merge replication from multiple remote SQL 2016 Express installations to a central SQL 2016 Server. This would be for reporting purposes so I would need all the express installations to report information to the central server daily.

The trouble I am having is that the main server is setup as the distributor and publisher (publisher is a blank database with the 41 tables we are wanting to report information into), and the express installs are all subscribers. Is this even possible and if it is, can someone point me in the right direction for documentation as I am not finding any for this purpose.

Thanks for all help!

Comment: Does my answer help - https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/43995/8783 ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this even possible

Yes.  Once you have the subscriptions created and initialized then you insert your data into the tables created on the subscribers.  The next time the subscriptions synchronize, the data will be sent to the publisher.