# Initialize replication sql server from backup of many databases

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication

I want to know how I can initialize a subscription from a backup of a publication database. I have three diferent databases that will point to the same subscriber. For the first time there is no problem but the second and the third one I have problems. How can I initialize the suscription without lossing the data from the first time and the data from the other two db integrate to the first?

Comment: See my answer [many to one replication](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/43995/8783).

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that.  Initializing from a backup is only appropriate when you want to overwrite the subscriber database.  In your scenario you should probably use regular snapshot initialization, so each subscription will create and load its own tables.