# Should I use Transactional Replication here?

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have a database on SQL Server A & one on SQL Server B. (SQL 2017 w/ enterprise) They share similar objects and need to be kept fairly up to date. Both will require changes to be passed to each of them, however these changes will be different. Should I setup transactional replication to go from server A to server B and then setup another publication to go back from server B to server A with the different criteria? I've never had to replicate different items from the replica. So that is why I am unsure here. Any comments are appreciated. I don't think Peer-to-Peer is the solution here as some objects will be different and/or not needed to be replicated between the 2 db's.

Comment: I don't think you have much other choice for multiple writable copies. Just keep in mind that you may need to use odd/even identity columns, or start using GUIDs to avoid collisions.

Comment: do you need to keep changes in server A from server B and vice versa ? If that is the case then ONLY T-Rep is your choice. See my answer -  [many to one replication](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/43995/8783) . You can adjust it as per your needs.